# My pygame/pyopengl code seems to apply a texture to every surface

Tags: python, pygame, pyopengl

I'm throwing some code together to help me better understand python, pygame, pyopengl, and 3D rendering. I've used code from two different places and I'm integrating them by writing my own code as I go. I've textured cubes in one program and made camera movement work in another. But when I put them together, the colors are wrong and surfaces that I don't intend to texture are affected. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out.

Here is what the two programs look like seperately.
[image: texture program], [image: camera movement program]

But when I put them together, I get this.
[image: garbled surfaces]

Here is my code, sorry I couldn't figure out how to attach it as a file!

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

import math

def tex_coord(x, y, n=4):
    """ Return the bounding vertices of the texture square.

    """
    m = 1.0 / n
    dx = x * m
    dy = y * m
    return dx, dy, dx + m, dy, dx + m, dy + m, dx, dy + m


def tex_coords(top, bottom, side):
    """ Return a list of the texture squares for the top, bottom and side.

    """
    top = tex_coord(*top)
    bottom = tex_coord(*bottom)
    side = tex_coord(*side)
    result = [
        (top),
        (bottom),
        (side),
        (side),
        (side),
        (side),
    ]
    """result = []
    result.extend(top)
    result.extend(bottom)
    result.extend(side * 4)"""
    return result

#block type names and location on template go here
BLOCK1 = tex_coords((3, 0), (3, 0), (3, 0))

def verts(x, y, z, n):
    vertices = (
        (1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), 1+(2*z)),
        (1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), 1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), 1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), 1+(2*z))
        )
    return(vertices)

print(verts(0, 0, 0, 1))



edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
    )

colors = (
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (0,1,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (1,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    )

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (6,7,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6)
    )


forced = False
def Cube(vx,vy,vz,block):
    if not forced:
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        y = 0
        for surface in surfaces:
            x = 0
            y+=1
            for vertex in surface:
                x+=1
                #glColor3fv(colors[x])
                glTexCoord2f(block[y-1][2*(x-1)], block[y-1][(2*x)-1])
                #print(block[y-1][2*(x-1)], block[y-1][(2*x)-1])
                glVertex3fv(verts(vx,vy,vz,1)[vertex])
        glEnd()


        
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for edge in edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glVertex3fv(verts(vx,vy,vz,1)[vertex])
        glEnd()
    else:
        texX = 0.75
        texY = 0.25
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glTexCoord2f(0.0+texX, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0,  1.0)
        glTexCoord2f(0.25+texX, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0,  1.0)
        glTexCoord2f(0.25+texX, 0.25)
        glVertex3f(1.0,  1.0,  1.0)
        glTexCoord2f(0.0+texX, 0.25)
        glVertex3f(-1.0,  1.0,  1.0)
        glEnd()

def loadTexture():
    textureSurface = pygame.image.load('texture2.png')
    textureData = pygame.image.tostring(textureSurface, "RGBA", 1)
    width = textureSurface.get_width()
    height = textureSurface.get_height()

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    texid = glGenTextures(1)

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height,
                 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData)

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

    return texid







pygame.init()
display = (800, 600)
scree = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)


glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1])
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1])

"""
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
glClearDepth(1.0)

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
#glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
#glCullFace(GL_FRONT)
##glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
##glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glDepthRange(0.0,1.0)
"""



sphere = gluNewQuadric() 

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
gluLookAt(0, -8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
glLoadIdentity()

# init mouse movement and center mouse on screen
displayCenter = [scree.get_size()[i] // 2 for i in range(2)]
mouseMove = [0, 0]
pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter)

loadTexture()

up_down_angle = 0.0
paused = False
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_PAUSE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
                paused = not paused
                pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter) 
        if not paused: 
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                mouseMove = [event.pos[i] - displayCenter[i] for i in range(2)]
            pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter)    

    if not paused:
        # get keys
        keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        #mouseMove = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
    
        # init model view matrix
        glLoadIdentity()

        # apply the look up and down
        up_down_angle += mouseMove[1]*0.1
        glRotatef(up_down_angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        # init the view matrix
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()

        # apply the movment 
        if keypress[pygame.K_w]:
            glTranslatef(0,0,0.1)
        if keypress[pygame.K_s]:
            glTranslatef(0,0,-0.1)
        if keypress[pygame.K_d]:
            glTranslatef(-0.1,0,0)
        if keypress[pygame.K_a]:
            glTranslatef(0.1,0,0)
        if keypress[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
            glTranslatef(0,0.5,0)
        if keypress[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            glTranslatef(0,-0.5,0)

        # apply the left and right rotation
        glRotatef(mouseMove[0]*0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        # multiply the current matrix by the get the new view matrix and store the final vie matrix 
        glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)
        viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

        # apply view matrix
        glPopMatrix()
        glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)

        #glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, [1, -1, 1, 0])

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glPushMatrix()



        Cube(0,0,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(1,0,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(0,1,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(0,0,1,BLOCK1)
        Cube(-2,0,0,BLOCK1)

        glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f(-10, -10, -2)
        glVertex3f(10, -10, -2)
        glVertex3f(10, 10, -2)
        glVertex3f(-10, 10, -2)
        glEnd()

        glTranslatef(-1.5, 0, 0)
        glColor4f(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
        gluSphere(sphere, 1.0, 32, 16)

        glTranslatef(3, 0, 0)
        glColor4f(0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 1)
        gluSphere(sphere, 1.0, 32, 16) 

        glPopMatrix()

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

pygame.quit()
```

I'd be very thankful if someone could explain this to me!

Edit: Thank you [Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902623/16738676)!!!

Here is a picture, and my working code.
[image: Correct textures!!]

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

import math

def tex_coord(x, y, n=4):
    """ Return the bounding vertices of the texture square.

    """
    m = 1.0 / n
    dx = x * m
    dy = y * m
    return dx, dy, dx + m, dy, dx + m, dy + m, dx, dy + m


def tex_coords(top, bottom, side):
    """ Return a list of the texture squares for the top, bottom and side.

    """
    top = tex_coord(*top)
    bottom = tex_coord(*bottom)
    side = tex_coord(*side)
    result = [
        (top),
        (bottom),
        (side),
        (side),
        (side),
        (side),
    ]
    """result = []
    result.extend(top)
    result.extend(bottom)
    result.extend(side * 4)"""
    return result

#block type names and location on template go here
BLOCK1 = tex_coords((3, 0), (3, 0), (3, 0))

def verts(x, y, z, n):
    vertices = (
        (1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), -1+(2*z)),
        (1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), 1+(2*z)),
        (1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), 1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), -1+(2*y), 1+(2*z)),
        (-1+(2*x), 1+(2*y), 1+(2*z))
        )
    return(vertices)

print(verts(0, 0, 0, 1))



edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
    )

colors = (
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (0,1,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    (1,0,0),
    (0,1,0),
    (0,0,1),
    (1,0,0),
    (1,1,1),
    (0,1,1),
    )

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (6,7,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6)
    )


forced = False
def Cube(vx,vy,vz,block):
    if not forced:
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        y = 0
        for surface in surfaces:
            x = 0
            y+=1
            for vertex in surface:
                x+=1
                #glColor3fv(colors[x])
                glTexCoord2f(block[y-1][2*(x-1)], block[y-1][(2*x)-1])
                #print(block[y-1][2*(x-1)], block[y-1][(2*x)-1])
                glVertex3fv(verts(vx,vy,vz,1)[vertex])
        glEnd()


        
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for edge in edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glVertex3fv(verts(vx,vy,vz,1)[vertex])
        glEnd()
    else:
        texX = 0.75
        texY = 0.25
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glTexCoord2f(0.0+texX, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0,  1.0)
        glTexCoord2f(0.25+texX, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0,  1.0)
        glTexCoord2f(0.25+texX, 0.25)
        glVertex3f(1.0,  1.0,  1.0)
        glTexCoord2f(0.0+texX, 0.25)
        glVertex3f(-1.0,  1.0,  1.0)
        glEnd()

def loadTexture():
    textureSurface = pygame.image.load('texture2.png')
    textureData = pygame.image.tostring(textureSurface, "RGBA", 1)
    width = textureSurface.get_width()
    height = textureSurface.get_height()

    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    texid = glGenTextures(1)

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height,
                 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData)

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

    return texid

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)



pygame.init()
display = (800, 600)
scree = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)


glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1])
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1])

"""
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
glClearDepth(1.0)

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
#glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
#glCullFace(GL_FRONT)
##glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
##glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glDepthRange(0.0,1.0)
"""



sphere = gluNewQuadric() 

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
gluLookAt(0, -8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
glLoadIdentity()

# init mouse movement and center mouse on screen
displayCenter = [scree.get_size()[i] // 2 for i in range(2)]
mouseMove = [0, 0]
pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter)

loadTexture()

up_down_angle = 0.0
paused = False
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_PAUSE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
                paused = not paused
                pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter) 
        if not paused: 
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                mouseMove = [event.pos[i] - displayCenter[i] for i in range(2)]
            pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter)    

    if not paused:
        # get keys
        keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        #mouseMove = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
    
        # init model view matrix
        glLoadIdentity()

        # apply the look up and down
        up_down_angle += mouseMove[1]*0.1
        glRotatef(up_down_angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        # init the view matrix
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()

        # apply the movment 
        if keypress[pygame.K_w]:
            glTranslatef(0,0,0.1)
        if keypress[pygame.K_s]:
            glTranslatef(0,0,-0.1)
        if keypress[pygame.K_d]:
            glTranslatef(-0.1,0,0)
        if keypress[pygame.K_a]:
            glTranslatef(0.1,0,0)
        if keypress[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
            glTranslatef(0,0.5,0)
        if keypress[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            glTranslatef(0,-0.5,0)

        # apply the left and right rotation
        glRotatef(mouseMove[0]*0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        # multiply the current matrix by the get the new view matrix and store the final vie matrix 
        glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)
        viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

        # apply view matrix
        glPopMatrix()
        glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)

        #glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, [1, -1, 1, 0])

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glPushMatrix()


        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        Cube(0,0,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(1,0,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(0,1,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(0,0,1,BLOCK1)
        Cube(-2,0,0,BLOCK1)
        
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f(-10, -10, -2)
        glVertex3f(10, -10, -2)
        glVertex3f(10, 10, -2)
        glVertex3f(-10, 10, -2)
        glEnd()

        glTranslatef(-1.5, 0, 0)
        glColor4f(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
        gluSphere(sphere, 1.0, 32, 16)

        glTranslatef(3, 0, 0)
        glColor4f(0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 1)
        gluSphere(sphere, 1.0, 32, 16)
        glColor3f(1, 1, 1)

        glPopMatrix()

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is a state engine. A state is kept until it is changed again. Two-dimensional texturing can be enabled and disabled, see [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml).

When texturing is activated, by default the color of the pixel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).
This causes that the color of the piles of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which you have set by [`glColor4f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

Set a "white" color and enable texturing before you render an object with a texture. Disable texturing before you draw an object with colors:

```py
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

# draw object with texture
# [...]
```

```py
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

# draw object with color
# [...]
```

---

Changes in your code:

```py
forced = False
def Cube(vx,vy,vz,block):

    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1)      # <--
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    if not forced:
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        for y, surface in enumerate(surfaces):
            for x, vertex in enumerate(surface):
                glTexCoord2f(block[y-1][2*(x-1)], block[y-1][(2*x)-1])
                glVertex3fv(verts(vx,vy,vz,1)[vertex])
        glEnd()

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)    # <--
        glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1)     
        
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for edge in edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glVertex3fv(verts(vx,vy,vz,1)[vertex])
        glEnd()

    # [...]
```

```py
run = True
while run:
        # [...]

        Cube(0,0,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(1,0,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(0,1,0,BLOCK1)
        Cube(0,0,1,BLOCK1)
        Cube(-2,0,0,BLOCK1)

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)      # <--

        glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f(-10, -10, -2)
        glVertex3f(10, -10, -2)
        glVertex3f(10, 10, -2)
        glVertex3f(-10, 10, -2)
        glEnd()
 
        # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly fast answer!